# In a computer simulation, what do you call the level that abstracts away the simulated world for computation?

Tags: word-request

In a computer simulation, what do you call the level that abstracts away the simulated world for computation? The simulation must be computed, so there's a level where the computation is done in a computer simulation, what do you call this level? Is there a word for it?

Comment: As far as I can tell, you already say it in your question: the so-called place where the computation is done (from the title of your question) is ***abstract***.

Comment: Do you mean the [back-end](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/back+end)? (See definition 2)